# (Android Butterknife) how to change text on button after clicking

Tags: android, butterknife

I have a button and I want to change text on it after it was clicked.

```
@BindView(R.id.btn) Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

} 
@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void click()
{
    btn.setText("anything");
}
```

I've realized that I can do this with normal onclickListener, but I am wondering if I can do this using butterknife.

EDIT

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jnx.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

EDIT

Error log

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jnx.test/com.jnx.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'btn' with ID 2131427422 for field 'btn' and method 'click' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required view 'btn' with ID 2131427422 for field 'btn' and method 'click' was not found. If this view is optional add '@Nullable' (fields) or '@Optional' (methods) annotation.
                                                                    at butterknife.internal.Utils.findRequiredView(Utils.java:92)
                                                                    at com.jnx.test.MainActivity_ViewBinding.<init>(MainActivity_ViewBinding.java:29)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.createBinding(ButterKnife.java:199)
                                                                    at butterknife.ButterKnife.bind(ButterKnife.java:124)
                                                                    at com.jnx.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
```

Line 22 in MainActivity is setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: I guess you have already done this.

Comment: Well, but it doesn't work. It crashes.

Comment: @jxn So  post the crash log and your gradle

Comment: Also you dont have to have this line: `@BindView(R.id.btn) Button btn;`

Comment: @Jois how is `btn.setText("anything");` supposed to work without this line?

Comment: @jxn No, it doesn't work. you are right

Comment: @jxn could you post the crash log?

Comment: Please also share your activity_main.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the view :

```
@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void click(Button button) {
    button.setText("Hello");
}
```

And you don't need this line so remove this:

```
@BindView(R.id.btn) Button btn;
```

Comment: @jxn Are you sure that you have a Button in your layout `(activity_main.xml)` with id `btn` ?

Comment: Sorry. I've restarted android studio and it helped. So I guess it is impossible to use both `@OnClick` and `@BindView`. Am I right?

Comment: @jxn No, it depends on your use case, if you are not going to use the view anywhere then `@BindView` is useless.

Comment: if there are multiple button how do i refer ? , lets say there are two button. a small example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. I think someone have posted such answer before, but it didn't worked for me at first. It started working after the restart of android studio.

```
@BindView(R.id.btn) Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

}
@OnClick(R.id.btn)
public void click(View v)
{
    btn.setText("dsdssd");
}
```

You have to pass the View as an argument.

Comment: `You have to pass the View as an argument.` - no it is optional.